# Accessing QCMobile API

Tags: node.js

I'm currently tasked with accessing data from the Department of Transportations QCMobile API, located [here](https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/developer/qcapi.page?cid=2135).

I've made an account and have obtained my key. I've tried accessing it through Ajax calls, Node's Request and https modules, and now I'm just trying to get a response via Curl.

Every time I try to access it I get the same error: error 403, Forbidden.

My URL appears to be properly formed, as seen here:

```
https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/44110/basics?webKey=xxxx
```

When I run it from Node or from an Ajax call, I only get 403, Forbidden.

Here is my relevant Node code:

```
this.url = 'https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/' + dotNumber + '/basics' + '?webKey=' + this.webkey;

this.options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: this.url,
};

this.getDoTData = function() {

    request(this.options)
        .then(function (response) {
            // Request was successful, use the response object at will
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // Something bad happened, handle the error
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

When I run it via Curl, I get the same 403 with some extra detail:

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas as to if I'm accessing this API incorrectly. There doesn't appear to be much documentation, and the page on their site where you can submit technical questions seems to be broken.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

This web service seems to be down for the time being.  These problems started during the maintenance window on weekend of Nov 18th, and it has been in varying degrees of non-operation since then.

This is the response I got from FMCSA customer support today:

> I do apologize about the inconvenience however, we have been experiencing technical difficulties with the App for a few weeks now. Our IT department is currently working on it however, at this time I do not have an exact time on when it will be fixed.

Comment: Ah, okay. I figured something was going wrong with it. Thanks for letting me know!